# TestFlight - What happens to the installed beta-app when that version goes live in AppStore?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

We're using TestFlight with external testers to beta-test our app. In the guidelines to TestFlight it states that `If you already have the live app installed on your device, the beta version of the app will replace the live version.`, but what about the other way around?

We uploaded a build to TestFlight a week ago, and started the beta-testing. Today, we released the same build on AppStore, and now - TestFlight says that we don't have any builds in beta, both on iTunesConnect and in the app. Did TestFlight 'understand' that we released the same version, and removed it from testing? Or did something else happen here..? I am not sure if this happened last time we did this.

What happens to the testers version of the app? It still has the orange beta-dot next to its name, will it update itself to indicate that it's the 'live' version? After all, it **is** the same build. Or will it 'expire' in 60 days? The real problem is that our beta-testers may be confused if it suddenly says that the app has expired, with no additional information in the TestFlight-app, and they have to install the live AppStore-version manually.

Answer (score 1):

The user can 'update' to the newest version on the App Store to remove the 60 days 'trial' for your beta version.

TestFlight checks your build version that is marked as test version and the live version on the App Store. If they match Testflight won't show the same version anymore.

Comment: But since it's the exact same version, the exact same build, will it show up as an 'update' in AppStore? Or will they have to uninstall the beta-version and re-install the live version?

Comment: They can 'update' to it as the app store knows the user has a beta version on it's device.

Also a tip: Always upload a new build that is going 'live' on the App Store. The system knows you've updated the build but also your users know you did some bug fixing.

Comment: Just FYI I talked to Apple just now and they said this is not the case and TestFlight installs are completely seperate to App Store builds and the user will need to uninstall the TestFlight build and install the App Store build as there is no upgrade path, but hey, what would Apple know? I suspect they're wrong but cannot check this behaviour. All I know is we had some TestFlight testers who could not find and install the new production update in App Store > Updates.